# How to access webpage hosted with localhost on other device using secure origin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, ssl-certificate

When I run node server using budo in localhost I am able to use full feature 
but when I try to run on a different device connected to the same network, I get this error:

> Only secure origins are allowed "
>   name:"NotSupportedError"

Later it directs to this website

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

I have tried to use all of this but nothing comes to the rescue.

Comment: Is the script served with a valid js mime type, eg application/javascript?

Comment: No I am using just getUserMedia